# How to append image canvas to img?

Tags: javascript

I crop the image and put it into canvas:

```
 image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            ctx.drawImage(
                image,
                0,
                0,
                dw,
                dh, 
                0,
                0,
                dw,
                dh,
            );
        });
```

How to get cropped image and put it to `body -> img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML canvas elements have a function called `toDataURL()`, which returns a data URL representation of the canvas pixels.

Call the `toDataURL()` function on the canvas element and set the image source to the data URL.

```js
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

---

#### Referance

- [`toDataUrl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)